# Specify only one leaf node with xpath from a given result

Tags: xpath

given

```
<a>
  <div><span></span></div>
  <div></div>
  <div><span></span></div>
  <div><span></span></div>
</a>
```

I want to only select n-th span

say, only 2nd span

**You CANNOT do this and declare victory:**

`//a/div[1]/span` Selects first span `//a/div[2]/span` selects second span tadaaa I win.

no

Imagine the structure of the HTML is dynamic.

I tried for example

`//a//span[2]`  but this doesn't work

E.g. after I want to `//a/div/span` get all leaflet spans, then select the second one for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this

```
(//span)[2]
```

or this

```
(//a//span)[2]
```

work for you?

Comment: oh nice, havent seen that before. Great, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! BTW I'm even not a programmer :)